# How to search a pattern including the whitespaces in awk?

Tags: bash, search, awk, whitespace

I want search a pattern which is kinda complex, I already learned I have to indicate \| instead of | in the script but how do I include the whitespace to match this exact pattern.

```
    TR40663|c0_g1_i2|m.33339 TR40663|c0_g1_i2|g.33339 ORF TR40663|c0_g1_i2|g.33339 TR40663|c0_g1_i2|m.33339 type:5prime_partial len:1730 (+) TR40663\|c0_g1_i2:3-5192(+) [specie]
```

I have to use this code which retrieves a sequence related with the ***pattern***

```
    awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";FS="\n"}NR>1{if ($1~/pattern) print ">"$0}' file
```

I don't know if the  ~/ is also messing with the code. Later on I will pass a list of elements inside multiple files but for now I want to check this pattern/search first.

Thanks for the help

Comment: @stark you cant use grep because grep is line-based, not record-based like awk, and so you can't specify a record separator with grep to search in and print multi-line records. The poster is using `>` instead of newlines to separate records. Andres - `~/` is not an operator. `~` is an operator and `/.../` are the static regexp delimiters. Get rid of the `/` from `~/` as I'm sure the syntax error is already telling you to do.

Comment: Whitespace has no special meaning in regexp patterns, so you don't need to do anything special to include them.

Comment: @Barmar but if I search that it returns several records treating each block separated by spaces as a string to search, that's the reason I want to match the exact pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/` is not an operator. `~` is the regexp comparsion operator and `/.../` are the static regexp delimiters. Get rid of the `/` from `~/` as I'm sure the syntax error is already telling you to do.

The syntax for using dymamic regexps is:

```
awk -v re='foo \\| bar' '$0 ~ re' file
```

or:

```
awk -v re='foo [|] bar' '$0 ~ re' file
```

Never use the word `pattern`, btw as it's ambiguous and misleading. In awk you should always use the words `regexp` or `string` while shell uses `globbing patterns` that are similar to regexps in functionality and syntax but very different in semantics.

Comment: Yes and his code uses `>` as the record separator, not `\n`. I'm sure given the dynamic regexp comparison syntax he's asking about he can work out the rest.

Comment: But how can I include the whitespaces? I have to match that exact string and If I put it verbatim it returns several records, I need only one record (which is the record per se and some text or sequence below) so I have to match that long line with spaces. Thanks for your help

Comment: Precisely as shown which already does include white space. There is nothing special about white space. Edit your question to include sample input and expected output and clarify the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

if `pattern` is an **awk variable** that holds a string representing the regex, then you have to write

```
if ($1 ~ pattern)
```

with *no slashes*.

if `pattern` is just a placeholder in your question for the actual regex, then you're missing the ending slash:

```
if ($1 ~ /pattern\|goes\|here/)
```

Notes:

- `~/` is not an awk operator
- the regex matching operator is `~`
- literal regex patterns are enclosed with slashes: `/foo.*bar/`

Comment: Yes, you are right I missed the final / but I this code has worked fine with a line like this {if ($1~/TR40663\|c0_g1_i2\|m.33339) before. My question is how to add whitespaces and avoid returning several matches I need only one match, exactly that long string which contains plenty of spaces.

Comment: If you want exactly that string, use string equality (`==`)  not pattern matching.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I tried ($1 ==>TR10023|c0_g1_i1|m.6923 TR10023|c0_g1_i1|g.6923 ORF TR10023|c0_g1_i1|g.6923 TR10023|c0_g1_i1|m.6923 type:complete len:176 (-) TR10023|c0_g1_i1:452-979(-) [name]) and also that string between "" but I could not find the match I must clarify I pasted the exact line I wanted to find, I am testing this with a smaller example and using gedit to double check it. –

Comment: You definitely need to quote the literal string.